# In database modelling, what kind of relation is it?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have  a table with persons and need store more than one number phone associated to one person to do this I create a second table with 2 fields idperson and  number the first field is a FK that references a one or many persons.

[image]

Is valid this approach?
This field (idperson) must be primary?
What kind of relation is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is valid.

While `idperson` is the PK of the first table, it alone can't be the PK of the second table, since you said that more than one phone number can be associated to one person. You could make a composite key of `idperson, number`. Alternatively, you could introduce a surrogate key, e.g. `idnumber`.

If you make a composite key, your second table represents a multivalued attribute in EER terms, and there's no relationship (between entity sets).

If you make a surrogate key, then the second table represents an entity relation with a denormalized relationship. The relationship is represented by the pair of entity keys `idnumber, idperson`. Since the PK constraint will be on only one of the columns, it would represent a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a valid approach.

Idpersona can't be primary key, because a person can have more phone numebers.

It is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: if I do idpersona primary I cant repeat id in this field but it is necesary store repeated values but I think that this field  nesesarily must be indexed, isn't?

Comment: @DavidUntama idpersona is primary only in the first table, in the second table it is a Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

1. It should work fine. Off course it depends on how your application is going to 
   handle the data.
2. ID should be primary key, and IDpersona Foreign Key.
3. Relation: One-To-Many. More info about it [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/relational-databases-defining-relationships-between-database-tables/).